# Django error to final deployment not finding url

Tags: django, heroku

any idea why this could not be working?? when in urls.py does not give any error except when in production.

this is the error when deploying.

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /admin
No module named 'djangopdf.project'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://pdfshellapp.herokuapp.com/admin
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'djangopdf.project'
Exception Location: /app/djangopdf/urls.py in <module>, line 18
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
 Server time:   Mon, 25 Nov 2019 04:34:24 +0000
```

this is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from djangopdf.project import views

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.HOME.as_view(), name='home'),
path('signup/', views.signup_views, name='signup'),
path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
path('main/', views.upload, name='main'),
path('logout/', views.logout_views, name='logout'),
path('login/', views.login_views, name='login'),
]
```

[image]

Comment: are you working with activated env

Comment: could you post your settings.py file?